# Exporting variables and reading them on another file with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I'm trying to export an array with some products from a javascript file to another but when I do a `console.log` to see what is in the array, all I get is "undefined".

Can someone help me with this?

Here's the code:

Products.js:

```
var products = [{
    name: "Nome: Headphones Audio Technica",
    price: "Preço: 169, 99€",
},
{
    name: "Nome: Teclado Logitech G512",
    price: "Preço: 98, 99€",
},
{
    name: "Nome: iPhone 11 128GB",
    price: "Preço: 579, 99€",
},
{
    name: "Nome: Xiaomi Redmi Buds 3 Pro",
    price: "Preço: 50, 99€",
}];

exports.products = products;
```

Main.js:

```
var products = require("./products");
console.log(products.products[clientChoice].name);
console.log(products.products[clientChoice].price);

//clientChoice is just so it only shows the product the client chose
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `exports.products = products;` to `module.exports = { products };`.

Comment: would I need to change anything on the other file if I wanted to export something else?

Comment: In other file (`Main.js`) you use `products.products`. If you want to export smth additional (for example `abc`) you can do it with `module.exports = { products, abc };`. After access from `Main.js` should be like this: `products.abc`.

Comment: Or you can import like `const { products, abc } = require("./products");` and have access directly to `products` and `abc` instead `products.products` and `products.abc`.